# access aspen plus through COM interface -- using python vs matlab

Tags: python, matlab, com, win32com, aspen

I have successfully accessed many different Aspen Plus variables through COM interface using Python (win32com), but failed to do so for the following variable, using the same command.

```
AspenPlus.Tree.FindNode("\Data\Reactions\Reactions\ReactionABC\Input\RVALUE_LIST\#1").Value = 11
```

However, this exact same command worked well using Matlab. It appears that python failed to deal with "#". How to fix this? Any suggestion or help will be highly appreciated.